# Ads and popups on my browser

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I am trying to browse on my Samsung android phone using Chrome and I keep on being redirected and having all this kinds of popups coming up. I have tried all solutions offered online and none is working. Please help me out because this is really pissing me off!!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike desktop, the mobile version doesn't have adblock which will stop all the *Redirects* you're facing. Try using UC browser, it's got inbuilt adblocker and on top of that it's really fast

Comment: Well... a browser which requires 31 different permissions doesn't seem quite a great choice for privacy, hmm? If OP is rooted, then simply having the open source AdAway app will solve most of their issues.

Comment: Still, even the open source Lightning browser does have inbuilt ad-block features, without needing all of these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're infected by a malware.
The solution is only delete your chrome browser app data.
long tap on chrome in app list drop it on app info then force close then delete app data.
keep in mind that if your browser infected by a malware then no adblocker will help.
also you can search for apps which is not installed by you in app manager find them then uninstall will help.
if you are on public network then definatlly your device may infected.

this link may little help
[here](https://androidforums.com/threads/android-chrome-redirection-virus-malware-adware.878655/)